# Double values returned from REST API JSON different from the call made from Python app engine application

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using Google REST API to collect metrics like CPU utilization for instances in a project from a Google App Engine built in Python 2.7, standard env. The implementation is based on this code given by Google:

```
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-metrics-export
```

The app engine code to collect CPU utilization metrics is like this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('monitoring', 'v3', cache_discovery=True)
timeseries = service.projects().timeSeries().list(
            name="my-project",
            filter="metric.type=compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"
            aggregation_alignmentPeriod=86400s,
            aggregation_perSeriesAligner="ALIGN_MEAN",
            aggregation_groupByFields="metric.labels.key",
            interval_endTime="2020-08-23T17:30:04.707Z",
            interval_startTime="2020-08-22T17:30:05.603000Z",
            pageSize=100
        ).execute()
```

It forms a REST API like this

```
https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/my-project/timeSeries?pageSize=500&interval.startTime=2020-08-22T17%3A30%3A05.603000Z&aggregation.alignmentPeriod=86400s&aggregation.perSeriesAligner=ALIGN_MEAN&filter=metric.type%3D%22compute.googleapis.com%2Finstance%2Fcpu%2Futilization%22+&pageToken=&interval.endTime=2020-08-23T17%3A30%3A04.707Z&alt=json&aggregation.groupByFields=metric.labels.key
```

If I try the REST API in a tool like Postman or if I try the Python code directly in shell editor, I get the metrics value in JSON format for Postman and Unicode format for shell editor which is the correct one:

```
      "value": {
        "doubleValue": 0.87114489514772131
      }
```

But when the same code is executed from the Python based Google App Engine application the response contained in the **timeseries** variable is returning a value in **Unicode** format which has a difference.

```
            "value": {
                "doubleValue": 0.8709659701719485
            }
```

### Update

This is happening for almost all metrics values of most instances.
The double values from the REST API are coming in **JSON** format, whereas the values called from app engine are coming in **Unicode** format and also in cloud shell editor they are coming in **Unicode** format but they are matching with the REST API values
I am new to Google App Engine and Python 2.7.

Comment: Are you using the same code in the App Engine and directly in the shell editor? If not, could you please share the one you are using?

Comment: Thanks. I got the api from the app engine logs only, the same code i am using in cloud shell editor. In app engine logs I am getting values returned like this:  "value": {"doubleValue": "0.8709659701719485"} which is different from rest api

Comment: This seems to be like an issue with the client library. I would recommend you to open a issue tracker here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. To the GCP team takes a look at it. Since you are using the same code and you are not getting the same result, I think that is the best option in this case.

Comment: Any reason to be using the discovery library instead of the idiomatic cloud library? https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/index.html